# Galaxy tab 2 10.1 is showing x and y coordinates and mouse lines on the screen

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

My Galaxy tab 2 10.1 is showing x and y coordinates across the top of the screen. When I swipe my finger on the screen, a line is trailing behind it, like what I am doing are showing. It was normal one day, then showing this the next day.

Does anyone know how to hide these details?

Answer (score 4):

Goto **Settings--> Developer options-->**(Uncheck) **Pointer location**.

Thats it.

Comment: I have a huawei raven doing the same thing but don't have the same options under accessibility. Cannot find where developer options is located

Comment: Tap on Build Number (under About Phone) 7 times. It will enable developer options.